# PHP Array Object to Serialize

Tags: php, arrays, json, serialization

I am trying to convert a PHP array object to an JSON.Following is the PHP Array Object;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Project\Man\Model\Branch Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 123456
            [name:protected] => Parent Branch
            [type:protected] => services
        )

)
```

I tried Serializing it but its not in a friendly readable object.

I tried the following:

> json_encode
>
> serialize

```
a:1:{i:0;O:23:"Project\Man\Model\Branch ":3:{s:5:"*id";s:36:"123456";s:7:"*name";s:20:"Parent Branch";s:7:"*type";s:8:"services";}}[{}]
```

I am trying for some solution where i can get JSON. any help.

Comment: If you just want json, you should only use `json_encode()`, not `serialize()`.

Comment: but its giving me a empty result.[{}] @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want json, you should only use json_encode(), not serialize().

Since your object properties are set as `protected`, they will however not be available when you encode the object whitout some additional help.

This is where the interface [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) comes into play.

You need to make sure that the object you want to encode implements the interface. Then you need to add a `jsonSerialize()` method to the class.

```
class Branch implements \JsonSerializable
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $type;

    // ... your class code

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        // Return what you want to be encoded
        return [
            'id'   => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => $this->type,
        ];
    }
}
```

If you now pass this object through `json_encode()` and you'll get a json string with what our new method returns.